# How can I check if a signal its periodic from the graph of FFT?

Tags: fft, dft, periodic

[image]

x is a vector of length 1000 that contains the samples of the signal;
n is equal to 16 that its the number of bits of each sample;
`fa=256 Hz` (sampling frequency);

```
Xf = fft(x);
stem(0 : 99; abs(Xf(1 : 100)))
```

And them i get this graph.

How can i write the x-axis in hertz?
How can i prove that the signal that originate this graph is periodic?

This is all the information i have.

Answer (score 1):

*This answers a "test question" rather than the title directly*

Depends what the question wants. Two possibilities:

1. "Yes" because the "full" DFT is [periodic in both domains](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Fourier_transform%2C_Fourier_series%2C_DTFT%2C_DFT.svg/1280px-Fourier_transform%2C_Fourier_series%2C_DTFT%2C_DFT.svg.png?1644755538162)
2. "Yes" because by "periodic" they mean $x(t) = x(t + T)$ holds for some $T > 0$, and for an *integer number of periods* in the finite sequence

Case 2 would yield an `abs(FFT)` that's zero in every other bin:

[image]

which is clearly true in your case (if we repeat `x` more times, we get more zeros)

---

#### Non "test question", briefly

For something more realistic, a brief answer is

1. *Can't tell from `abs(FFT)`*: the `abs` tosses out phase, which decides the actual placements of various modulations, which is a critical piece of information to deciding whether a pattern repeats sequentially. The integer periods case is an (unrealistic) exception.
2. *FFT alone is too weak*: if any modulation that's present in the periodic sequence of interest is also present elsewhere, it'll overlap in the FFT domain and pollute our readings. A *time-frequency* method like STFT and CWT are much more suited as they disentangle modulations and their relative positions. We'd then apply a self-similarity measure or template matching like autocorrelation to determine if some pattern repeats.
3. Regardless of what we do, we cannot tell if anything is periodic *outside the measured interval* without additional knowledge (e.g. physical properties of the system)

---

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(0)

x0 = np.random.randn(12)
x0f = rfft(x0)

x1 = np.hstack([x0, x0])
x1f = rfft(x1)

# it won't look same, I used my own plot library
plt.plot(np.abs(x0f)); plt.show()
plt.plot(np.abs(x1f)); plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1000 samples in `x` and take the `fft` (in what I am assuming is MATLAB) you will find there are 1000 samples in `Xf`.

The frequency spacing of these samples is equal to the sample rate divided by the number of samples so: `df = fa / length(Xf)`.  The conventional ordering for the out of the FFT is 0 to half the sample rate, followed by -half of the sample rate back up to 0, so the total span is - to + the [Nyquist](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nyquist_frequency&oldid=1016916999) rate.

Using this information to update the axis on your plot:

```
df = fa / length(Xf);
stem((0 : 99) * df; abs(Xf(1 : 100)))
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
```

As you have only a sample of data, it is impossible to determine if the signal is periodic.  It may have any behavior outside of where you measured it, periodic or not.  What you can do it talk about the frequency content within the data you have sampled, and that is indeed what you have in your figure.

Comment: I disagree with _"impossible to determine"_; inferring periodicity of a measured signal is a perfectly valid inquiry. _"may have any behavior outside"_ is true but immaterial, unless of course it is the goal, then more info's needed (unclear from OP). I think a little rewording would help. The -1's from me.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I'd be interested in seeing your algorithm to determine the periodicity of a signal from a finite set of samples.

Comment: This is a question from a test and i only have this information and its suposo to say if its periodic or not. But it possible to determine its period, if yes how can i determine it?