# Is there any rule of thumb for determining periodicity of a signal just by observation of mathematical expression?

Tags: periodic, terminology

Is there any way(rule of thumb) to determine periodicity of a signal just by observation of mathematical expression as rule of thumb mentioned in attachment for determining time invariance of a system[image]

Comment: No, there's no rule of thumb for periodicity, other than the definition of periodicity! Why would you need a rule of thumb? The job of a rule of thumb is being easier than the precise definition, but the precise definition is "$f(t)$ is periodic with period $T$ iff $f(t+T)=f(t)$ for all $t$"; I wouldn't know what could be made *easier* about this definition.

Comment: (Warning: nitpicking ahead) ... as long as $T>0$.

Comment: @MBaz: as long as you admit to the possibility of a negative period, then $f(t + T) = f(t)\ \forall\ t$ implies $f(t - T) = f(t)\ \forall\ t$.  So, the definition still holds.

Comment: @TimWescott OK, but you'd still need $T \neq 0$ in that case. Also, you'd need to redefine the fundamental period to be the smallest period in absolute value, instead of just the smallest period (which is the usual definition).

Comment: True.  And it's a bit silly.  But (with your caveat about $T \ne 0$) it still _works_.

Comment: [Related](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/81520/50076)